# How to avoid repetitive filter specification in mako %def's?

Tags: python, template-engine, mako

I find myself repeating the same filter attribute over all the %def's in my mako code:

```
<%def name="mydef1(a,b)" filter="trim">
# something something something
</%def>

... 

<%def name="mydef2(b)" filter="trim">
# something something something
</%def>
```

Is there a way to specify a default set of filters for all %def's and avoid the repetitive 'filter="trim"' in my code?

I noticed there is [an option to specify default filters for expression filters](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html#the-default-filters-argument), but i could not find something similar for %def's.

Comment: There is option called [`buffer_filters`](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#mako.template.Template.params.buffer_filters), which is able to specify default filters for the `%def`'s. However it works only for `%def`'s defined with `buffered="True"`. I think the best solution is to raise issue in the [Mako's repository](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/mako/issues) and ask for adding this functionality. Or you always can monkey patch the `DefTag` class to add filter to every `%def` >.<

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple workarounds you can use:

1. You can use the [`default_filters`](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html#the-default-filters-argument) argument if you are okay
   [importing the `defs` programmatically](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/defs.html#calling-defs-programmatically) or by [loading them from
   a file](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#using-file-based-templates).
2. You can [nest the defs](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/defs.html#defs-within-defs) within a parent def, and apply the
   filtering to the parent def (I don't have mako on my current machine, so I can't text this, but I am 99% sure this works, please call me out if I am wrong.)

   ```
   <%def name="filterdefs()" filter="trim">

       <%def name="mydef1(a,b)">
       # something something something
       </%def>

       <%def name="mydef2(b)">
       # something something something
       </%def>

   </def>
   ```
3. Finally, you could use [`buffer_filters`](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#mako.template.Template.params.buffer_filters) as suggested in the
   comments. However, instead of adding `buffered="True"` you can just
   call the `def` with [`capture(myDef)`](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html#buffering) instead of `myDef()`